# Using class instead of struct and constructor issues

Tags: c++, class, constructor, struct

I am trying to move from using structs to using classes, and I have a few questions with my - not fully complete, but enough to illustrate my queries - code (thank you in advance for clarifying these):

1. I am having problems with creating a constructor that takes in arguments, specifically the line in the header file that I have currently left as `neighborAtt(int neighbor_id, int att_1, int att_2);`.

   When using `neighborAtt` as a struct, I could do it easily as `neighborAttributes currentNode(neighborID, att1, att2);`. What is the class-equivalent?
2. In the .cpp file, I know that I need to define the constructor as `neighborAtt::neighborAtt()`.

   Do I need to this with the functions (i.e. include neighborAtt::) or is what I've done accurate?

This is my header file:

```
#if !def connectivity_H
#define connectivity_H

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

class listAtt;
class vecListAtt;

class neighborAtt //contains the neighbour and associated attributes of a node
{
public:
    neighborAtt();
    neighborAtt(int neighbor_id, int att_1, int att_2);


    vecListAtt connFrFile(int file_ext);
    vecListAtt makeList(std::vector<std::list<neighborAtt>> nodeAndInfo, int nodeID, neighborAtt neighAndAtt);  
    neighborAtt getAtt(std::string currentLine);

private:
    int neighborID;
    int attribute1;
    int attribute2;
};

typedef std::list<neighborAtt> listAtt;
typedef std::vector<listAtt> vecListAtt;

#endif
```

and the .cpp file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "connectivity.h"

neighborAtt::neighborAtt(): neighborID(0), attribute1(0), attribute2(0) {}

//neighborAtt::neighborAtt constructor with arguments 

vecListAtt connFrFile(int file_ext)
{
    //code
}

neighborAtt getAtt(std::string line)
{
    //code
}
```

Comment: what's with a wall of code and text :-(

Comment: Every function of class `neighborAtt` needs to be scoped as such in the .cpp file (i.e. `neighborAtt::getAtt(....)`). This goes for your constructors too (all your constructors). What "problems" are you having with your ctr taking the three ints?

Comment: When you say going from structs to classes, do you mean literally changing "struct" to "class" or are you talking about some higher-level concept?  A struct and a class are the same thing in C++.  The only difference is that things in a struct are public by default, and things in a class are private by default.  Perhaps you mean that you want to use things that structs and C don't provide, such as member functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second constructor (one with the arguments) you do just the same as for one without them. Or did I get the question wrong? It'd be like:

```
neighborAtt::neighborAtt(int neighbor_id, int att_1, int att_2)
 : neighborID(neighbor_id),
   attribute1(att_1),
   attribute2(att_2)
{
}
```

And for the methods you must go the same way:

```
vecListAtt neighborAtt::connFrFile(int file_ext)
{
    //code
}
```